# how to unblock google service (adsense) from ContentSecurityPolicy next js

Tags: next.js, content-security-policy, adsense

I'm building a NextJs application, and I'm trying to set a secure header in my project's next.config.js file. and every time i request to google like adsense and other default google services it is also blocked, is there a way to handle this, so that it is not blocked

[image: Error Console]

this is my code

```
const ContentSecurityPolicy = `
  default-src 'self';
  script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' *.google.com *.doubleclick.net *.googleadservices.com *.googlesyndication.com *.googletagmanager.com *.google-analytics.com;
```

Comment: _"Content Security Policy: Duplicate script-src directives detected. All but the first instance will be ignored."_ - It seems you have more than one `script-src` directive defined, which could be preventing the one you shared to be applied.

Answer (score 1):

There are likely two root problems or your errors:

1. An error message says "Content Security Policy: Duplicate script-src directives detected. All but the first instance will be ignored." As the CSP you shown does not have duplicate script-src, it could be from another CSP. CSP can be defined in both response header and as a meta tag. Check both and see if one of them has multiple script-src defined. It is ok to have multiple CSPs with one script-src each. As content has to pass all policies, another CSP can only make it stricter.
2. You have not defined frame-src. There are errors due to iframes, and they fall back to default-src in your CSP, which only allows 'self'.